# How do I stop hovering over an <a> tag from increasing padding-bottom?

Tags: html, css

Now on my second month of learning HTML & CSS, I'm practicing designing and styling website headers.  However, I've encountered an issue which I'm unsure how to resolve.

I've created an anchor tag which creates a border-bottom when hovered over, however in doing so it appears to add padding-bottom to the div in which it's contained.

I will attach both the HTML and CSS below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated; I'm sure it's a small fix, but it's one I don't know yet!  Thanks in advance.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-top-logo {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-top-2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-top-logo-2 {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.header-main a {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-main a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-top">
  <span class="header-top-logo">Busby &#38; Kane</span>
</div>

<div class="header-top-2">
  <span class="header-top-logo-2">Independent Funeral Directors</span>
</div>

<div class="header-main">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-top-logo {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-top-2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-top-logo-2 {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.header-main a {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.header-main a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-top">
  <span class="header-top-logo">Busby &#38; Kane</span>
</div>

<div class="header-top-2">
  <span class="header-top-logo-2">Independent Funeral Directors</span>
</div>

<div class="header-main">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved the issue instantly.  Many thanks and a new lesson learned!